# In GHCi, why can't I show `pure 1` in REPL?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, ghci

I tried to assign a lifted value to `a`.

```
λ> :m Control.Applicative
λ> let a = pure 1
```

When I evaluated `a` in REPL, it prints `1`.

```
λ> a
1
```

Therefore, I thought there may be an implementation of `show` for `a`, and tried this:

```
λ> show a
```

But the GHCi throws an error:

```
<interactive>:70:1-4:
    No instance for (Show (f0 a0)) arising from a use of ‘show’
    The type variables ‘f0’, ‘a0’ are ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (a, b, c)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
      ...plus 32 others
    In the expression: show a
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = show a
```

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Did you try checking `:type a`? That would tell you something, maybe.

Comment: @AJFarmar Actually, not that much, since GHCi does not default `m` to `IO`, yet.

Comment: One bit of meta-explanation is in order. While you may think of GHCi as a "Haskell interpreter", it's actually a rather different sort of beast. It's a tool for developing Haskell programs interactively. Whereas Haskell worries a lot about keeping things nice and consistent, GHCi cares mostly about convenience and utility.

Answer (score 19):

GHCi is defaulting the `Applicative f => f` to `IO`. When you do

```
λ> a
1
```

you actually run an `IO Integer` action such as

```
λ> let a = return 1
λ> a
1
```

GHCi by default prints the result of `IO` actions. Hence the `1` in the result line. (Quite confusingly, this `1` is not the value of `a`, nor the output of running `a` as an `IO` action -- just the returned value of the latter.)

GHCi uses a sophisticated heuristics to handle user input. First, it tries to `show` it, possibly defaulting some type classes like numeric ones. This fails in your case. When that fails, it tries to see if the input is an `IO` action. In such case, the action is run and, if the result can be `show`ed, it is printed.

Note that this GHCi magic only happens at the top level.
When you try to `show a`, GHCi tries its magic on the whole `show a`, not on `a`, so the same effect does not happen.