# why getCurrentTime function from Data.Time.Clock.POSIX does not work as expected?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get UTC time into my program by using **Data.Time.Clock.POSIX** library but **getCurrentTime** function is not working as expected but **getPOSIXTime** is working fine?

```
Prelude> import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
Prelude Data.Time.Clock.POSIX> getPOSIXTime
1577786745.6127777s
Prelude Data.Time.Clock.POSIX> getCurrentTime
Prelude Data.Time.Clock.POSIX>
```

Is this known behaviour or I am missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `getCurrentTime` returns (inside `IO`) `UTCTime`, which has no `Show` instance, hence GHCi runs the IO action, but does not print the result.

```
> t <- getCurrentTime
> :t t
t :: time-1.8.0.2:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime.UTCTime
> t

<interactive>:14:1: error:
    * No instance for (Show
                         time-1.8.0.2:Data.Time.Clock.Internal.UTCTime.UTCTime)
        arising from a use of `print'
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I have no idea about why `UTCTime` has no `Show` instance.

---

Update: the instance exists but it is an orphan! So, we need to import another module to bring it into scope.

```
> import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
> getCurrentTime
> import Data.Time.Clock  -- bring Show instance into scope!
> getCurrentTime
2019-12-31 10:53:03.6132023 UTC
```

Comment: But data UTCTime has show instance. check here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:UTCTime

Comment: I'm curious as to why, in that case, GHCi is seemingly doing nothing in the OP's session. I would expect it to give an error regarding the lack of a `Show` instance, exactly as you quoted from your session.

Comment: @RobinZigmond GHCi runs any `IO T` action. Then, if `T` is showable (but not `()`), it calls `print` on the result. I guess it can be more convenient this way if you want to run the action and observe its side effects, and do not care for the result (?). Otherwise, we would need to bind the result `_ <- action` every time an IO action returns a non printable. I do not have a strong opinion on this one.

Comment: @Saurabhkukade Ah, right. See the edit. The issue is that the instance is in another module (a so-called "orphan" instance).

Comment: Oh! Now I understand it. Thanks!!

Comment: @chi thanks, I thought GHCi always implicitly called `print` on the result, and therefore gives an error if the type isn't an instance of `Show`. I guess I've got that wrong, although I'm sure I remember seeing `no instance of Show` errors in GHCi in similar situations :shrug:

Comment: @RobinZigmond That happens when the expression type is not inside IO. GHCi is rather magic: on non-IO value, it prints it (or errors out), on IO actions it runs them and prints the result when possible (except `()`). More magic happens in defaulting types. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464891/in-ghci-why-cant-i-show-pure-1-in-repl/30464979#30464979